# Why was Kirk in the Nexus, but not the rest of the crew?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-generations

In *Star Trek: Generations*, the Enterprise-B is hit by the nexus energy wave. Kirk dies and is later found in the nexus.

**But why was he the only one there?** If that energy wave was the nexus, shouldn't all the crew members be there as well? What happened in that explosion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Kirk was on deck 15 at the time. The hull breach (with which the Nexus had contact) occurred only on sections 20-28 on decks 13, 14 and 15.

Kirk would have been sucked into space and into the Nexus. Presumably the area was evacuated (other than Kirk) or perhaps other crew members in that part of the ship managed to either hold on, or perhaps they are also in the Nexus - we don't see much more of the Enterprise B to find that out, but this definitely explains why the entire crew wasn't drawn in.

Comment: It was the shakedown cruise so I think they were running on a skeleton crew. Pretty sure that's mentioned somewhere in the film.

Comment: They added fairings around the main deflector of the Enterprise-B (as compared to Excelsior) explicitly so they could have a portion of the ship that could be hit and sheered off, but plausibly only have one person in it.